# Iron-router - Can't access multiple data contexts

Tags: meteor, iron-router, spacebars, meteor-helper

I need to access multiple data sources from my template helpers. I managed to send multiple data sources with iron-router.

```
//router.js
...

papers: function() {
  return Papers.find();
},
data: function() {
    return {
      papers: this.papers(),
      check: {
        done: 'ok'
      },
      open: 'upper'
    };
}

...
```

The problem is that i'm not able to access these object's properties more than two levels deep.

What I mean by this is that:

```
<template name="page">
  {{pageName}}
</template>

...

Template.page.helpers({
  pageName: function() {
    return this.papers.name;
  }
}
```

Throws an error.

While:

```
Template.page.helpers({
  pageName: function() {
    return this.papers;
  }
}
```

renders: [object Object], which is OK

The same happens with the object literals: this.check.done throws error, but this.open renders 'upper' correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `this.papers` is initially undefined until the data is loaded. You get an error when you try to access `name` property of undefined.

Simply add a check and it should work:

```
Template.page.helpers({
  pageName: function() {
    return (this.papers) ? this.papers.name || '';
  },
};
```